# How to capture both stdout and stderr at the same using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, real-time

I am implementing a CI platform and need to run a bunch of tests in a shell script that need to be delivered and analyzed in real-time. I figured I needed to use `subprocess.Popen` and use `.stdout.readline()` to get the output upon execution. A sample of that is demonstrated below:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "script.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if process.poll is not None and output == "":
        break

    if output:
        # do whatever you want with the output
        print(output.strip())
```

The above code works, however, during the course of execution, there maybe errors. I would have to use `process.stderr.readline()` to get the errors but I want to be able to get the **errors** and **output** as a single object (string) not separate objects (strings).

Comment: `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` will combine both together into one useless, mangled string, which you can access with `process.stdout`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy FWIW, +1 for "useless"

Answer (score 2):

Pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to `Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "script.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that have been "asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sorry, I don't have an encyclopedic knowledge of every question asked on SO.

Comment: (Especially since the linked question is only tangentially the same as this one.)

Comment: Thanks @mipadi I tried your solution and it works.